# TailwindCss dark: on VueJs router-link does not apply certain style

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have an Application with a Navigation Bar, which I wanted to style in both a normal and a dark mode. When applying styles to my  elements using `active-class` and `class`, some of the styles aplly to the active router-link while others do not.

This is my declaration of the router-link

```
<router-link
  v-for="view in this.views"
  :key="view.to"
  :to="view.to"
  active-class="py-2 px-2 font-semibold border-b-4
                text-green-500 border-green-500
                dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-gray-900 dark:border-gray-200"
  class="py-2 px-2 font-semibold transition duration-300
         text-gray-800 hover:text-green-500 hover:bg-gray-300 rounded
         dark:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:bg-gray-300"
>
  {{ view.text }}
</router-link>
```

The styling of `dark:text-gray-200` on the `active-class` for example does not apply to the Element, but when I change the value to e.g. `dark:text-indigo-200` it does apply.

I am just completely clueless where I could have gone wrong.
I know that I didnt post all Code, but I cannot post the whole html due to being to huge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Kind regards

EDIT:
tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./public/**/*.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Please share the `tailwind.config.js`*

Comment: just edited the post so it includes the tailwind-config

Comment: it looks fine, I thought that you override the colors in the theme section

Comment: yeah, I tried every Idea i have and it seems it just wont change to certain color shades.